# How come ansible template appends False

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have a template that is used to build out a config file.  Basically, I want the line setting the value to always be there in the file, but to comment it out of the variable isn't actually defined.

```
{{ proxy_loadmodule is defined and proxy_loadmodule is not none | ternary('','# ') }}LoadModule={{ proxy_loadmodule | default('') }}
```

Currently, the variable `proxy_loadmoduel` isn't defined so I would expect it to output `# LoadModule=`.  Instead, though, I get `FalseLoadModule`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses

```
{{ (proxy_loadmodule is defined and proxy_loadmodule is not none) | ternary('','# ') }}LoadModule={{ proxy_loadmodule | default('') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-undefined-variables) into a condition and test the length. Enable the default also when the variable evaluates to false (None) by setting the second parameter of the filter `true`. This way you test all cases (undefined, None, and empty string) in a single condition. For example, the template

```yaml
shell> cat test.conf.j2
{% if proxy_loadmodule|default('', true)|length > 0 %}
LoadModule={{ proxy_loadmodule }}
{% else %}
# LoadModule=
{% endif %}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('template', 'test.conf.j2') }}"
```

gives (abridged) if the variable *proxy_loadmodule* is not empty

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e proxy_loadmodule=proxy_module
...
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    LoadModule=proxy_module
```

Otherwise, when the variable *proxy_loadmodule* is undefined, None, or empty the configuration line will be commented out

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
...
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    # LoadModule=
```